# How do I read the position data from a GPS (NMEA) device?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gps

I'm trying to read data from a GPS device (NMEA). I am getting the data successfully. However, as soon as I start using it, it gives me gibbirish. This is what I get from the GPS:

```
$GPGSA,A,3,20,25,31,22,14,29,03,16,32,06,27,,1.5,0.8,1.3*33
$GPRMC,120556.000,A,2546.0985,S,02816.0193,E,0.22,276.44,291013,,,A*7A
$GPGGA,120557.000,2546.0984,S,02816.0191,E,1,11,0.8,1396.3,M,21.5,M,,0000*71
$GPGSA,A,3,20,25,31,22,14,29,03,16,32,06,27,,1.5,0.8,1.3*33
$GPGSV,3,1,12,31,50,165,19,14,48,055,27,16,43,304,42,32,36,265,38*76
$GPGSV,3,2,12,29,24,119,31,06,19,355,34,20,14,238,41,25,10,138,19*78
$GPGSV,3,3,12,27,09,351,33,22,06,008,36,03,05,341,36,23,,221,*7F
$GPRMC,120557.000,A,2546.0984,S,02816.0191,E,0.17,274.76,291013,,,A*7D
$GPGGA,120558.000,2546.0982,S,02816.0189,E,1,11,0.8,1396.0,M,21.5,M,,0000*72
$GPGSA,A,3,20,25,31,22,14,29,03,16,32,06,27,,1.5,0.8,1.3*33
$GPRMC,120558.000,A,2546.0982,S,02816.0189,E,0.07,220.52,291013,,,A*7B
$GPGGA,120559.000,2546.0981,S,02816.0187,E,1,11,0.8,1395.7,M,21.5,M,,0000*7A
$GPGSA,A,3,20,25,31,22,14,29,03,16,32,06,27,,1.5,0.8,1.3*33
$GPRMC,120559.000,A,2546.0981,S,02816.018
```

The above was received by doing the following:

```
//inside a 100ms ticker
Dim data As String = GpsPort.ReadExisting()
CommentBox.AppendText(data)
```

As soon as I do `Dim strArr() As String = data.Split("$")` then output it using:

```
CommentBox.AppendText(strArr(0).ToString) // inside the same ticker
```

the output is:

```
034.000,2546.0985,S,02816.0298,E,1,11,0.8,1360.6,M,21.5,M,,0000*77
3,20,29,14,22,31,25,03,16,32,06,27,,1.5,0.8,1.3*33
MC,121034.000,A,2546.0985,S,02816.0298,E,0.01,236.13,291013,,,A*75
.000,2546.0983,S,02816.0297,E,1,11,0.8,1359.9,M,21.5,M,,0000*7A
A,A,3,20,29,14,22,31,25,03,16,32,06,27,,1.5,0.8,1.3*33
,121035.000,A,2546.0983,S,02816.0297,E,0.06,283.04,291013,,,A*72
036.000,2546.0982,S,02816.0296,E,1,11,0.8,1359.3,M,21.5,M,,0000*73
3,20,29,14,22,31,25,03,16,32,06,27,,1.5,0.8,1.3*33
MC,121036.000,A,2546.0982,S,02816.0296,E,0.03,190.30,291013,,,A*72
.000,2546.0981,S,02816.0296,E,1,11,0.8,1358.6,M,21.5,M,,0000*75
A,A,3,20,29,14,22,31,25,03,16,32,06,27,,1.5,0.8,1.3*33
3,1,12,31,49,161,28,14,46,052,20,16,45,301,39,32,36,268,35*79
3,2,12,29,23,122,18,06,21,355,27,20,15,240,40,27,11,351,37*78
```

Can anyone assist me in getting the GPS co-ordinates from the `GPGGA` strings? Because splitting them clearly doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the data line by line.
Each line is one NMEA sentence.

Once you detect "$GPGGA" (or you also could use the RMC message)
you have this line:

```
$GPGGA,120557.000,2546.0984,S,02816.0191,E,1,11,0.8,1396.3,M,21.5,M,,0000*71
```

Now you splitt by delimiter ","

Then this is latitude : 2546.0984,S
And this is longitude 02816.0191,E

read at NMEA spec which format the coordinates are: I think: the  first to digits in latitdue are degrees, the rest is minutes: 25° 46.0984 minutes. If "S" multiply the result with -1.

slightly different  for longitude: 
02816.0191,E

first 3 digits degrees, rest minutes.  27° 16.0191 minutes. multiply with -1 if "W".

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the messages you are seeing are part of a rather complicated message format. Each part means something different and the meanings depend on the message type.

You may want to look at some of the code in [this open source project](https://github.com/EmitCode/NGps). I wrote this library with a colleague and it parses out those messages from a specific GPS device, but it should work with pretty much any device putting out the same data.